# Label not recognised

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm trying to implement a basic program in LC3 Assembly, but the assembler seems not to be recognising one of the labels. I wonder why it's not recognising just the last one:

```
.ORIG 0x300
NUMBER: .FILL x0006
NUMBER2: .FILL x0003
R1MAGG: .FILL x0999
UGUALI: .FILL 0x500
R1MIN: .FILL x0001
LD R1, NUMBER
LD R2, NUMBER2
;I stored in R1 and R2 2 numbers
;Now I compare them
NOT R2, R2
ADD R2, R2, #1
ADD R3, R1, R2
BRp R1MAGGIORE
BRn R1MINORE
LD R4, UGUALI
JSR EOP

R1MAGGIORE: 
    LD R4, R1MAGG
    JSR EOP

R1MINORE:  
    LD R4, R1MIN
    JSR EOP

EOP:
    .END
```

And this is the error it's returning: *LINE 28: Unrecognized opcode or syntax error at or before '.END'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `EOP: HALT` and then the `.END` on the next line as you have it.  Suspect it is complaining about missing instruction, but you really should terminate the program with a `HALT` (trap) instruction anyway.

---

Are you sure you want `.ORIG` at 0x300 not x3000?

---

You might consider putting your data after the code, to prevent the simulator from attempting to execute your data.  Otherwise you can put a `BR MAIN` as the first instruction (i.e. before/in-front-of the data), and a label `MAIN:` where you have the programs first real instructions, so that it will jump around your data and to your program starting point.

Comment: Closing the simulator and reopening it made it, but I will still accept your answer.
P.S. The tip given about adding a BR MAIN made me solve tons of warnings, thanks